# Adding Link to image in slideshow cycle2 or pager

Tags: html, dreamweaver, jquery-cycle2

I need to add a link to images in my slideshow(cycle2) which is also setup with a pager. How do I do that without knocking the image down of the slider??

```
 <div 
 id="slideshow" class="cycle-slideshow"
 data-cycle-manual-fx="scrollHorz"
 data-cycle-pager-fx="fade" 
 data-cycle-manual-speed="400"
 data-cycle-prev="#prev"    
 data-cycle-next="#next"
 data-cycle-speed="600"  
 data-cycle-timeout="3000" 
 data-cycle-pager = "#pager" 
 data-cycle-pager-template="<a href='#'><img src='{{src}}' width=150     height=100></a>">


    <img src="bear scene.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="someimage.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="otherimage.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="picute.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="somethingelse.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="anotherpic_.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="lastpic.jpg" alt=""/>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to mess up with the css (which you need to do if you wrap the images in `<a>` tags) you can just use javascript `onclick` event for the images to open a link from the images like this:

```
<img onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank')" src="bear scene.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Here are some examples: https://jsfiddle.net/2jjomuge/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am very new to this and only can see HTML code on your answer. How do I apply the event in javascript. I did something like this:                                                                                  <img  onClick="myFunction" src="revenant1.jpg" alt=""/>   then            <script>
                               function myFunction()
                              {
 window.open('http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/playlist/title_design/the_grid/', '_blank');
 }
Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link to some different examples in jsfiddle. Take a look and let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: Yep still not working. I can see that on the link that you provided me the images are static and I think that the problem that I am encountering is that my image is inside a jquery cycle2 slide show and a pager below the slider. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I had little simple mistake of spelling on the HTML code. The second myFunction2 is working perfectly!

Comment: Nice to hear you got it working and glad to help! :)